# When the line graph of a line graph gives us the original graph?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

**Definition:**

Let $G$ be a graph, the [line graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_graph) of $G$ denoted of $L(G)$ is defined as follows:

-The vertices of $L(G)$ are the edges of $G$

-Two vertices of $L(G)$ are adjacent iff their corresponding edges in $G$ are incident G.

**Question?**

Let $G$ be $d$-regular graph. For $d=2$, $G$ will be cycle graph, in this case it is easy to check that $L(G)=G$, thus $L(L(G))=G$ ($i.e.$ line graph of the line graph gives us the initial graph).

My question is for which $d\geq 3$ we have $L(L(G))=G$?

I think that $L(L(G))=G$ if and only if $d=2$, but I'm not sure how to prove it.

Any idea will be useful!

Comment: +1 for question and answer, I think I can use this result as check for my linear algebra implementation of the mapping $L(G)$...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is pretty easy!

**Proposition:**

Let $G$ be $k$-regular graph (that is $d(G)=k$), then
$L(L(G))=G$ if and only if $k=2$

**proof**

-If $k=2$, then $L(L(G))=G$.

-If $L(L(G))=G$, then $$d(L(L(G)))=d(G)=k$$

But we know that $d(L(G))=2k-2\Rightarrow d(L(L(G)))=4k-6$, then 
$$4k-6=k\Rightarrow k=2$$

Comment: Great answer, well explained and well proven.